# calcular horas com javascript

Tags: javascript

quero calcular o tempo percorrido entre duas horas:

```js
var h1 = 23:14:32;
var h2 = 22:55:27;
var total = h1 - h2;
```

o retorno que pego é NaN.

Comment: Na verdade isto nem é para executar, esta sintaxe não existe. O que deseja fazer é extramente mais complexo e as pessoas costumam usar bibliotecas para isso, ou fazer gambiarras que funcionam muito mais ou menos, portanto não confiável.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function formatar_segundos(h,min,s) {
 return (h*3600)+(min*60)+(s);
}

var data = formatar_segundos(23,14,32);
var data2 = formatar_segundos(22,55,27);

var diferenca = data_format(data-data2);
function data_format(s) {
 this.h = Math.floor(s/3600);
 this.min = Math.floor((s - (this.h*3600))/60);
 this.s = s - (Math.floor(s/60)*60);
 return this.h + "h "+ this.min + "min "+this.s + "s";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ele está retornando propriedade global NaN, que é um valor especial que significa Not-A-Number (não é um número), pois vc esta setando apenas strings nas variáveis.

Use essa função para iniciar e leia documentação da API jquery que pode lhe auxiliar. 
:)

Jquery Documentação: https://api.jquery.com/

NaN = https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date(); //seta o objeto Date
  var n = d.getHours() -2; //subtraí 2 horas da hora atual
  return n; 
}
console.log(myFunction()); //exibi "apenas" o valor da hora atual menos 2hrs (sem os minutos)
```